# Why "Use same selection" option is missing in Android Studio 3.0 and later?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

In Android Studio 2.x, it looks like this:
[Android Studio 2.x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dalts.png)

But now in Android Studio 3.0, the option "Use same selection" is missing.
[Android Studio 3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKqTp.png)

Why is the convenience option deprecated? Is there move to any other places I didn't find?

Comment: I suspect it is related to the Instant Run feature.  If the app is already running, Instant Run will mean that the app gets incrementally updated instead of re-run. To get the target device dialog again, you need to stop the running app.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3.0 is still Beta version, if I am correct. So you can't assume that it is deprecated. Maybe it will be there with the release version.

As to your current problem, look for the same option in `Run/Debug Configurations`.

Select `USB Device` for `Target` and select the checkbox underneath.
That should do it.

[image]